# Implement "Calender" view in iPad application, just like a default calendar of iPad device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there any best or simple way to implement a calendar view in iPad application just like calendar app in iPad ?

Thanks in advance
Tejas

Answer (score -2):

There is Easy To Use [Open Source iOS Calendar](https://github.com/square/objc-TimesSquare) View Supporting All NSCalendar Calendars.